# MySQL Null Safe Equals incorrect on Numeric types?

Tags: mysql

This one bit me today and it seems like a bug. It seems like when comparing the result of the `LOCATE` function in MySQL that it behaves totally different when using the not equals `<>` versus the null safe version `<=>` See the session below:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.25, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

mysql> SELECT LOCATE('A', "The Apple");
+--------------------------+
| LOCATE('A', "The Apple") |
+--------------------------+
|                        5 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT LOCATE('A', "The Apple") <=> 0; -- WRONG!?
+--------------------------------+
| LOCATE('A', "The Apple") <=> 0 |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOCATE('A', "The Apple") <> 0;
+-------------------------------+
| LOCATE('A', "The Apple") <> 0 |
+-------------------------------+
|                             1 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The null safe version returns 0 (false) which seems odd to me. The `LOCATE` method's [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) doesn't specify what happens with nulls, but I tested it and it does return null for something like `LOCATE('A', null)` but the real issue seems to be comparing the integer that `LOCATE` returns to `0`.

I checked the [documentation on <=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) but it just says:

> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

Which doesn't really tell me why `0 <=> 5` comes back `0` and `0 <> 5` comes back `1` The only thing I could think of was that MySQL says:

> These operations work for both numbers and strings. Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary.

And maybe there was an automatic cast, but that doesn't make any sense since doing the check directly (typing out `0 <=> 5`) shows the same issue.

Does anyone know what's causing this? Or where in the documentation this is indicated? It seems like a pretty major issue if the null-safe equality operations return invalid results for as simple a comparison as 5 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Null safe equality comparison **`<=>`** (spaceship) operator is an *equality* operator. It works like the **`=`** equality comparison operator, except with the bit about not returning NULL.

To get "inequality" out of that operator, you would need to negate it, for example

```
 SELECT NOT ( 0 <=> 5 )
```

Comment: DOH! 
Guess my eyes are glazing over and didn't notice this silly mistake.

Comment: To be fair, it does look more like the inequality operator `<>`than an equality `=` operator. As goofy as it looks, it's much handier than the alternative syntax we'd need to use to accomplish what it does. (I'm not  sure if the parens around the comparison are required with the NOT... I tend not to keep track of the precedence of operators, and assume the reader won't either. The parens make my meaning explicit... I want to do the comparison first, and then do the negation.